# Port a linux distribution on risc-v architecture

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

I want to port a Linux distribution that is not yet ported to risc-v architecture. I dont have much knowledge about porting but i know about risc-v ISA(Instruction set Architecture). I want to know can i port a Linux distribution. I have ported debian to riscv in qemu simulator but it was already ported. Like if i want to port a debian distribution like Kali Linux or Parrot OS from where should i start. What should i need to do to port Kali Linux or Parrot OS to riscv.

Comment: Do you mean you get RISC-V versions of Debian packages ? Or you run qemu in a RISC-V system and run Debian x86 packages on top of it ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to port a Linux distribution that is not yet ported to risc-v architecture. I dont have much knowledge about porting but i know about risc-v ISA(Instruction set Architecture)

Porting a full distro is a lot; don't start with that. Start with figuring out how to cross-compile packages on that distro, for some architecture it already supports; e.g. figure out how to build arm64 packages on your x86 PC.

> I have ported debian to riscv in qemu simulator but it was already ported.

Congratulations! That sounds like good work.

> Like if i want to port a debian distribution like Kali Linux or Parrot OS from where should i start. What should i need to do to port Kali Linux or Parrot OS to riscv.

Kali Linux, basically being a castrated debian, won't get ported by itself – instead, it will just be based of the risc-v debian. If you want to have these distros on these platforms, talk to the community, to the maintainers of these distros. Ask them, in all honesty, what it kind of contribution it would take to get the distro ported to risc-v, and explaining that you were able to do it for debian, what *you* can contribute here.

A port of a distro is not primarily a *technical* issue, but a workforce and organizational issue. Someone has to actually build the packages. There's a lot of packages. Where does the compute power for that come from? I know I used to be responsible for a medium-sized C++ project that debian packages (might even be part of Kali, don't know), and building the package for x86_64 on x86_64 takes about an hour on the debian build systems, usually. It'll typically take *much* longer in qemu, so doing it with a native cross-compiler is *very* desirable. So, maybe making sure all the tools needed to get the Kali-shipped software built for risc-v is ready and useful for cross-compilation would be my nr. 1 priority.

I don't know Parrot, but it also seems to be based on debian, so the same applies.